# how mysql write new data in its files which storaged in file system when I update data

Tags: mysql

I want to know, when I update the middle data of a table, how mysql write the new data into the file which storaged in file system? Create a template file to storage the after part of the middle data?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fundamental concept that you *really **must*** get your head around.

```
Database != File
```

*Most* of what your Database does happens *in memory*, not on disk.

When you make any change in a database, a lot happens before that change gets written out to a Data File on disk.

- First, the "change vector" is written into the "Transaction Log" (which, admittedly, *is* on disk, for recoverability),
- Second, the change is applied to a Data Block inside the Buffer Cache, a big chunk of *memory* containing many, *many* "bits" of the database.
- At some point "later" - and different DBMSs have *wildly* differing views on *how much* later that can be - the Data Block gets pushed out and actually written to disk.

This is why your should **never** use purely *file-based* tools to work with a Database - file-based tools can only see what's in the *files* and most of what the database is doing just isn't in there - yet.

For more background, have a read through *some* of the [MySQL Architectural documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pluggable-storage-overview.html).
Be warned, there is an *awful lot* in there, but the basics should help.  (And you get it all this *for free*!)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  The data is stored in "blocks" of 16KB each.  The blocks are not necessarily in 'order'.  When you Update, Insert, or Delete a row in the middle of the table, it goes into (or is deleted from) the appropriate block.

If that block is not too big, it will be "split" into two blocks.  They are placed somewhere in the "file" that contains the data.

See "BTree" for how the blocks can be kept track of.  The data is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (A BTree uses the ordering.)